# DOS DEBUG trace command doesn't work as I would expect

Tags: debugging, assembly, dos, x86-16, tasm

I have ASM code which print `abc` using looping syntax. Here is my code

```
;abc.com
.model small
.code
org 100h
start:
    mov ah, 02h
    mov dl, 'a'
    mov cx, 3h

ulang:
    int 21h
    inc dl
    loop ulang

    int 20h
end start
```

the COM program run normally 
[image]

result of `debug abc.com` followed with `-t` looks like
[image: NOP after int 21]

The question is why it's `NOP` after `INT 21`, instead of `INC dl`? AFAIK it should `INC dl` then `LOOP xxxx` for three times then `INT 20`.

When I press `-t` continously it's go somewhere I don't know till crash, means can't find `INT 20h`

it's different with `debug abc.com` followed with `-u`
[image: red arr indicate loop]

it's show `INC dl` and `LOOP 0107` which indicate looping.

FYI:

- Win 7 Ultimate SP 1 32 Bit
- GUI Turbo ASM x86 3.0
- Celeron Dual Core n2840

Comment: int 21h is an interrupt handler with its own code. With the `t` command you stepped into the int 21 handler code.You'll notice CS:IP went from 1400:0107 to 00A7:107C

Comment: You might wish to consider the `p`command instead of `t` when you reach  an `int` like `int 21h`. `p` by itself should execute all the code in the interrupt handler and then break on the next instruction after that which would be `inc dl`

Comment: @MichaelPetch `p` works like expected, but what is the differences between `p` and `t`? I mean the differences between proceed with trace/step?

Comment: `t` will step (trace) into the code of a function (`call`) and and a software interrupt handler (`int`). `p` doesn't step into a function when using `call` or step into the code of an `int`. `p` will execute a function or an interrupt handler in its entirety and then break on the next instruct after the `int` or `call`. `p`roceed is more like _STEP OVER_ and `t`race is more like _STEP INTO_

Comment: @MichaelPetch got it, please answer and I will mark it as solved. Thanks in advance mate.

Comment: FWIW, DOS debug implements `p` by placing an INT 3 after the CALL/INT. It then allows the program to run at full speed. When the INT 3 is hit it removes the INT 3. So normally the INT 3 isn't visible to the user. However on rare occasions the INT 3 can mess something up. For example some assembly routines can return either to the instruction after the call or to the instruction starting at +2 after the call. If the routine returns to +2 then the INT 3 isn't hit and isn't removed by the debugger. More modern debuggers will use a hardware breakpoint instead of INT3 to avoid this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `T`race command in debug is the equivalent of the *STEP INTO* feature of modern day debuggers. The `int` instruction (like `call`) executes a series of instructions and then returns back to the caller. `T`race will step into a software interrupt handler or a function and execute each instruction one at a time. The [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722863.aspx#XSLTsection135121120120) documentation for debug says this about `T`race:

> Executes one instruction and displays the contents of all registers, the status of all flags, and the decoded form of the instruction executed.

In your case you hit `int 21h` and jumped to the software interrupt handlers code at *CS:IP*  00A7:107C . If you trace through all the interrupt handler code you'd eventually reach *CS:IP* of 1400:0109 where the `INC DL` instruction is.

In order to execute a function or interrupt without stepping through each instruction associated with it, you can use the `p`roceed command. Proceed is akin to the *STEP OVER* feature of modern day debuggers. The code of an interrupt handler or a function/subroutine will execute and then break on the instruction after the *INT* or *CALL* instruction.

The documentation says this about *PROCEED*:

> When the p command transfers control from Debug to the program being tested, that program runs without interruption until the loop, repeated string instruction, software interrupt, or subroutine at the specified address is completed, or until the specified number of machine instructions have been executed. Control then returns to Debug.